# C++ static vs global with pointers?

Tags: c++, class, static, global

In C++11 I wrote (in global):

```
static MallocMetadata *dummy_block = &MallocMetadata{};
```

And I got a warning that I am taking address of temporary.

1. Why is this a warning? isn't static living until the end of my main.cpp file?
2. When I changed it to:

   ```
   static MallocMetadata dummy_block = MallocMetadata{}, *last_free_block = &dummy_block;
   ```

I didn't get a warning regarding last_free_block why is that?

Comment: Why not just `static MallocMetadata dummy_block = MallocMetadata{};`? Why must you have a pointer?

Comment: In both cases, `MallocMetadata{}` constructs a temporary that ceases to exist immediately after `dummy_block` is initialised. In the first case (if, hypothetically, it was allowed) `dummy_block` would be a dangling pointer (a pointer to an object that no longer exists) - but that is disallowed by a rule that disallows taking the address (i.e. what you're doing is a diagnosable error, not just a warning).  In the second case, `dummy_block` is initialised as a COPY of the temporary (although, in C++11, the compiler is permitted to elide the temporary).

Answer (score 2):

The compiler does not complain about `dummy_block` being a temporary, but `MallocMetadata{}` is a temporary. In this line:

```
static MallocMetadata *dummy_block = &MallocMetadata{};
```

Lifetime of that temporary last till `;`. You can store a pointer to it, but immediately after the initialization the pointer becomes useless.

PS: Your 2. seems to be ok-ish, but it is unclear why you insist on a pointer when you need to store the object somewhere anyhow:

```
static MallocMetadata dummy_block;
```

And anywhere you are using `dummy_block` use `&dummy_block` instead.

Comment: I though the compiler is smart enough to know that since I am pointing to something then I need that something...

Comment: @ariel compiler is smart enough to know what? The compiler isnt smart at all, it just follows the rules and a temporary is a temporary

Comment: @ariel Yes you can just use `new` if you **really** want to use a pointer.
`static auto ptr = new MallocMetadata;`

Comment: @ariel - The compiler is smart enough to emit diagnostics on your code, because the standard (which is the yardstick against which correctness of all compilers are assessed) specifies that the sort of thing you're trying is a diagnosable error.   The standard does not require the act of taking the address of an object, and storing the address in a pointer, to extend the life of the object.